# flycheck mode ruby/chef checker - foodcritic vs. cookstyle

Tags: flycheck, ruby-mode

I use standard ubuntu emacs (27.1) with flycheck mode from melpa (reinstalled today).

Chef/Cinc is a ruby based Infrastructure as Code language.  Flycheck mode has been working very well with these .rb files and offering chef specific linting.

Recently I upgraded chef 15 to cinc 17 on my laptop and flycheck started having fits because "foodcritic" just returned 1 and some error messages because it has been depreciated.  I've been unable to see where or how flycheck engages the foodcritic executable.

The replacement is "cookstyle".  I've tried symlinking foodcritic to cookstyle, but having cookstyle end with a non-zero exit code seems to have been upsetting.  So I've replaced foodcritic with a simple shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
cookstyle "$@"
exit 0
```

and now I get no linting at all.  So I guess I need to customize flycheck mode to use cookstyle properly?  Any hints?

I'm not very proficient at elisp but I know how to use the scratch buffer to execute stuff and how to save stuff in ~/.emacs.

Thanks for any help.

My emacs mode is displayed as "Ruby EditorConfig FlyC".

Comment: Unless you want to write your own checker for `cookstyle`, you may be better served by supporting the existing feature request at https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/issues/1935

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are exactly right.